# Loading I18n files in a gemified plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rubygems

I'm building a gemified plugin with Rails 4. For the most part, it works as expected, but I can't get the I18n to work. When I try, I get this error:

```
translation missing: en.errors.messages.no_revisions_made
```

My I18n file looks like this:

```
#config/locales/en.yml
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      no_revisions_made: "You must edit at least one attribute"
```

While the I18n call looks like this:

```
I18n.t("errors.messages.no_revisions_made")
```

I'm assuming this is happening because the plugin is not loading the en.yml file. How can I prompt it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a standard gemified plugin cannot do this. However, a [Rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) can. A Rails Engine has all the same functionality as a gemified plugin, but with extra perks. For instance, it can have self-contained models, views, and controllers--as well as I18n files, routes, and initializers.